# _objc_retain", referenced from:__ARCLite__load error in Xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.4

I've recently upgraded to Xcode 4.4 and have been using it for some Mac App Store submissions. Two worked fine but the third gave this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_objc_retain", referenced from:
      ___ARCLite__load in libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o)
     (maybe you meant: _objc_retainedObject)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

ARC is turned off so I don't know where this reference is coming from, or how to get rid of it. I've tried the usual clean/build cycle but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume that you have tried  turning the Build active architecture only to "Yes" in the Project -> Build Setting -> Architectures, right?

Comment: Are you using any ARC-enabled frameworks in this application?

Answer (score 16):

I think you should use the SDK 10.6 on Xcode 4.4,right? 
If so, please Change "Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support" to "NO".

Comment: This worked for me but what is the impact of changing that setting?

Comment: Never ask *why* when working on older SDKs.  Just thank the person who posted the answer and move on!  Thank you @aleon - it worked for me too.  (I got there by starting a project in Xcode 7, using ARC, latest SDK, and then later converting it to build on the 10.6 SDK with manual retain/release so I could test some of its code for use in an older project.)

Answer (score 2):

Is your base sdk lower than 5.0? I'm using Xcode4.5, and get the same error when i building with iOS 4.2.After I changed it to iOS5.0(or above), the error disappeared.

I'm sorry,you talked about Mac app.But i think the reason may be the same.
OK，i found an answer: Change "Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support" to NO may work.

Comment: Changing "Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support" to NO worked for me (iOS 4.2 deployment target with Xcode 4.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Xcode 7.0.1 with iOS 7.0. The solution was to change the Deployment Target from 7.0 to 7.1.